# <select> tag want a vertical scroller on options

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please visit this link first: http://jsfiddle.net/UWNtK/

Here is a `<select>` tag with number of options. I have done it getting inspired by this tutorial here: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Now I need all the options to be wrapped under a div, so that there will be a vertical scroller (in case of category1).
How this output can be obtained?

I'm using this Html:

```
<div class="drop1">
    <select>
        <option value="categ1">Category1</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="drop2">
    <select>
        <option value="categ2">Category2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.drop1, .drop2 {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 34px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(images/dropdwn.png) no-repeat right #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #f00;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0 10px;
}
.drop1 select, .drop2 select {
    background: transparent;
    width: 215px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #f00;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.drop1 option, .drop2 option {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt this can be done cross-browser (or in any browser) using just the <select> element.

Comment: @KevinB- Is there a easy jquery way? most preferred one?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use a JavaScript solution I'm afraid.

Try something like: [jQuery Selectbox plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)